# Setting and getting value of select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about setting value of `select` drop down with jQuery

I've written this code

```
// This should find option I want and set it as selected
jQuery('[name=' + obj.name + ']').val(obj.value)
     .find("option[value=" + obj.value + "]").attr('selected', true);

// This should set value of select to the same as above
jQuery('[name=' + obj.name + ']').val(obj.value);
```

Providing that `obj.name = "selManufacturer"` and `obj.value` is any of option values of below select, I have this problem:

The first piece of code seem to work. I can see that my option is selected. But when I want to get `.val()` of `select` I get an empty string. Any idea why?

```
<select style="display:none;" class="js-ManufacturerList" name="selManufacturer" id="ManufacturerList">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Microsoft">Microsoft</option>
    <option value="HP">HP</option>
</select>
```

When I do

```
jQuery("#ManufacturerList").val() // ""
jQuery("#ManufacturerList option:selected").val() // ""
jQuery("#ManufacturerList").find(":selected").text() // ""
```

This only happens in Firefox

Comment: what is obj? can u provide the html as well? need more details.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sayinoboto/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This looks like it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vcx11nd6/

Comment: Updated it. Might be detailed now

Comment: In Firefox 35.0.1, using this: http://jsfiddle.net/uc59esgz/ I get *Microsoft* for the first three, and *HP* for the second three.